# (JSON) RFC7158 vs RFC7159

Tags: json, rfc

What's the difference between [RFC7158](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7158) and [RFC7159](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7159)?

For me they seem to be the same ([diff](https://author-tools.ietf.org/iddiff?url1=rfc7158&url2=rfc7159&difftype=--html)), so what was the reason for creating 7159 after 7158?

The only explanation I've found was this, but it's not too exact:

> This document has been replaced by [RFC 7159](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc7159/) due to a publication error in [RFC 7158](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc7158/).

Comment: either typo's or they just fixed certain explanations

Comment: Both RFC 7158 and RFC 7159 are moot because [we're on RFC 8259 that replaces both of them](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259) - so the 715X specs are just footnotes now.

Comment: they mostly add errata for such and not issue a new RFC right after

Comment: That's true, Dai, but has nothing to do with my question..

Comment: The only change (except the RFC number itself) seems to be the year. So perhaps the original 7158 had the year 2013 as a typo? Once a standards document has been published, it can't be changed. To update a standards document a new one has to be published, even for such seemingly small typos.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right. They wrote 2013 in the document, but in 2013 March this was not yet done. Maybe that's it. Thanks.